# how to render html loaded from API inside ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm opening a modal this way:

```
const modal:HTMLIonModalElement =
   await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalLoteinfoPage,
      componentProps: {
         pageBody:pageBodyLoadedFromAPI
      }
});
```

Then I'm trying to put the content `pageBody` as HTML inside `ion-content`

```
<ion-content>

  <div [innerHTML]="{{pageBodyLoadedFromAPI}}"></div>

</ion-content>
```

So I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{pageBody}}] in ng:///ModalLoteinfoPageModule
```

What exactly this error means? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use binding [] you don't have to use interpolation {{}}, only the variable name.

```
<div [innerHTML]="pageBodyLoadedFromAPI"></div>
```

You have to use interpolation if you don't use binding

```
<div innerHTML="{{pageBodyLoadedFromAPI}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`pageBodyLoadedFromAPI` is a angular variable. No need for `{{}}`

```
<div [innerHTML]="pageBodyLoadedFromAPI"></div>
```